# Determine if an Rectangle is closer to a Circle than another Rectangle

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, geometry, rectangles

Suppose we have two rectangles A, B and a circle R. We would like to determine if for any three points r, a, b such that "r \in R, a \in A, b \in B", "dist(r, a) < dist(r, b)" will always hold? The dist() returns the Euclidean distance between two points. In other words, we want to test if A is closer to R than B.

Note that the rectangles and circles could be hyper-rectangles and hyper-spheres in high-dimensional space, and the rectangles are axis-parallel.

Is there any testing algorithm that runs in polynomial time (regarding the number of dimensions D)? Is O(D) possible?

PS: the testing should be sound and complete, i.e., no false positives or true negatives.

Comment: It sounds from your comment to an answer here that "if A is closer to R than B" has a different definition of "closer" than the typical one. Could you outline it without using mathematical correlations? For instance, if you have rectangle-circle-rectangle laid out in an axis, where the distance between the first rectangle and the circle is less than between the circle and the other rectangle, I'm not sure that dist(r, a) < dist(r, b) for *all r*, but it would fit my definition of *closer*.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can just consider the center of your circle. If the center is closer to one rectangle, then the circle is closer. Next, compare your center point to the planes defining a rectangle to segment it into one of several possible volumes (basically, how many of the planes of the rectangle does it lie on the proper side of). For the remaining planes (that it does not lie on the proper side of), find the distance along each axis from the point to the plane, and treat this as your distance vector. It's norm is the euclidean distance from the center of your circle to the rectangle. This solution should be O(d), and quite nice to implement since your rectangles are axis-aligned.

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand "If the center is closer to one rectangle, then the circle is closer." Actually there is correlation between dist(a, r) and dist(b, r), since a and b should be connecting to the *same* point r.

Comment: What I mean is that you don't need to consider the radius of your circle. If you know the center of your circle, just get the distance from the center to each rectangle, and subtract your radius from that to get the actual distance. But since you just care about which is closer, you don't need to do the subtraction. If `a < b` then `a - r < b - r`

Comment: You cant just consider the center. Take the following example: http://imgur.com/FxeUQVh
According to your conditions, the circle is closer to the left rectangle. But there is a point inside the circle whose minimal distance to the other rectangle is smaller than to the first. So none of the recangles is closer to the circle according jojers Condition.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood. So OP wants to test if every point in R is closer to every point in A than any point in B, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since we are working in N-dimensional space, let's call those objects `NBox` and `NBall`.  These define N-dimensional volumes.

Assuming that the axes of the box are aligned with the canonical unit vectors of euclidean space, then an `NBox` can be represented as either two N-dimensional double arrays `Min` and `Max` along the coordinate axes, or as a single N-dimensional list of `Range<double>` projections onto the coordinate axes.  An `NBall` can be represented as a single N-dimensional double array `Center` and a double `Radius`.  An `NPoint`, a single N-dimensional point, like so (in c#):

```
public interface INDimensional
{
    int Dimension { get; }
}

public class NPoint : INDimensional
{
    readonly double[] point;

    public NPoint(double[] point)
    {
        if (point == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (point.Length < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.point = point.ToArray(); // copy
    }

    public int Dimension { get { return point.Length; } }

    public double this[int i] { get { return point[i]; } }

    public IList<double> Coordinates { get { return Array.AsReadOnly(point); } }
}

public class NBall : INDimensional
{
    readonly NPoint center;
    readonly double radius;

    public NBall(double[] center, double radius)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(radius) < Accuracy.AbsoluteDoubleTolerance)
            this.radius = 0;
        else if (radius < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        else
            this.radius = radius;
        this.center = new NPoint(center);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int Dimension { get { return center.Dimension; } }

    public double this[int i] { get { return center[i]; } }

    public NPoint Center { get { return center; } }

    public double Radius { get { return radius; } }
}

public class NBox : INDimensional
{
    readonly double[] min;
    readonly double[] max;

    static void ComputeExtremes(double[] point1, double[] point2, out double[] min, out double[] max)
    {
        if (point1 == null || point2 == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        if (point1.Length != point2.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        min = new double[point1.Length];
        max = new double[point1.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < point1.Length; i++)
        {
            // Handle double-precision rounding issues where point1[i] and point2[i] so nearly equal that they somehow got inverted.
            min[i] = Math.Min(point1[i], point2[i]);
            max[i] = Math.Max(point1[i], point2[i]);
        }
    }

    public NBox(double[] min, double[] max)
    {
        ComputeExtremes(min, max, out this.min, out this.max);
    }

    public int Dimension { get { return min.Length; } }

    public Range<double> this[int i] { get { return new Range<double>(min[i], max[i]); } }

    public IList<double> Min { get { return Array.AsReadOnly(min); } }

    public IList<double> Max { get { return Array.AsReadOnly(max); } }
}
```

So firstly, given an NPoint, what is the closest point on an NBox?  It can be done coordinate-by-coordinate.  To get the ith coordinate value of the closest point, see if it falls inside the ith range of the box.  If inside, the coordinate value is the coordinate value of the point.  If smaller, the coordinate value is the value of the range minimum.  If larger, it is the range maximum.

```
public static class NDimensionalExtensions 
{
    public static bool FindClosest(this Range<double> range, double other, out double closestParameter)
    {
        if (other <= range.Min)
        {
            closestParameter = range.Min;
            return false;
        }
        if (other >= range.Max)
        {
            closestParameter = range.Max;
            return false;
        }
        closestParameter = other;
        return true;
    }
}

public class NBox 
{
    public bool FindClosest(NPoint other, out NPoint closestPoint)
    {
        if (other.Dimension != Dimension)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        double[] closest = new double[other.Dimension];
        bool allInside = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++)
        {
            allInside = allInside && this[i].FindClosest(other[i], out closest[i]);
        }
        closestPoint = new NPoint(closest);
        return allInside;
    }
}
```

Secondly, given an `NBox`, what is the closest point to another NBox?  Well, this isn't uniquely defined, because if the boxes overlap in some range along an axis, any coordinate value inside the overlap of the ranges could be chosen.  However, since we're only interested in eventually calculating *distances*, this doesn't matter, we can just choose the center of the overlap:

```
public static class NDimensionalExtensions 
{
    public static bool FindClosest(this Range<double> range, Range<double> other, out double closestParameter)
    {
        if (other.Max <= range.Min)
        {
            closestParameter =range.Min;
            return false;
        }
        else if (other.Min >= range.Max)
        {
            closestParameter = range.Max;
            return false;
        }
        // return in the middle of the overlap
        closestParameter = 0.5 * Math.Max(range.Min, other.Min) + 0.5 * Math.Min(range.Max, other.Max);
        return true;
    }
}

public class NBox 
{
    public bool FindClosest(NBox other, out NPoint closestPoint)
    {
        if (other.Dimension != Dimension)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        double[] closest = new double[other.Dimension];
        bool allInside = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++)
        {
            allInside = allInside && this[i].FindClosest(other[i], out closest[i]);
        }
        closestPoint = new NPoint(closest);
        return allInside;
    }
}
```

Now that we know how to compute the closest points between boxes and points, it's easy to get distances between boxes, points, and balls.  The distance between two points and/or boxes is the distance between the closest points, or zero if they intersect.  The distance between an `NBall` and a box or point is the distance between the closest points, less the radius, or zero if the difference is negative (intersection).

```
public interface INDimensional
{
    double GetDistance(NBox other);
}

public class NPoint : INDimensional
{
    public double GetDistance(NPoint other)
    {
        if (Dimension != other.Dimension)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        double distSq = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++)
        {
            var dot = (this[i] - other[i]);
            distSq += dot * dot;
        }
        return Math.Sqrt(distSq);
    }

    public double GetDistance(NBox other)
    {
        NPoint closestPoint;
        if (other.FindClosest(this, out closestPoint))
            return 0;
        return GetDistance(closestPoint);
    }
}

public class NBall : INDimensional
{
    public double GetDistance(NBox other)
    {
        NPoint closestPoint;
        var allInside = other.FindClosest(Center, out closestPoint);
        if (allInside)
            return 0;
        double distance = closestPoint.GetDistance(Center) - Radius;
        if (distance < 0)
            distance = 0;
        return distance;
    }
}

public class NBox : INDimensional
{
    public bool FindClosest(NBox other, out NPoint closestPoint)
    {
        if (other.Dimension != Dimension)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        double[] closest = new double[other.Dimension];
        bool allInside = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++)
        {
            allInside = allInside && this[i].FindClosest(other[i], out closest[i]);
        }
        closestPoint = new NPoint(closest);
        return allInside;
    }

    public double GetDistance(NBox other)
    {
        NPoint myClosest, boxClosest;
        if (FindClosest(other, out myClosest))
            return 0;
        if (other.FindClosest(this, out boxClosest))
            return 0;
        return myClosest.GetDistance(boxClosest);
    }
}
```

Given the `GetDistance(NBox other)` method on `INDimensional`, you can now find out which among a collection of `INDimensional` objects is closest to a given `NBox`.

This could be optimized by using distances squared, BTW.

So, all this looks O(N).

However, what if the boxes are axis-aligned along axes *other than the canonical coordinate axes*?  In that case, it will be necessary to transform all the points into axis space, or to take dot products with the axes to produce the correct intervals.  And *this* will be O(N-squared), because transforming a N-dimensional point into another coordinate system requires N-squared multiplications.

I didn't define the `Range<double>` class, you can do that yourself.  I haven't actually tested the code above yet since you were interested in the algorithm not the implementation.  Finally, here's the stub of an `Accuracy` class:

```
public static class Accuracy
{
    public static double AbsoluteDoubleTolerance
    {
        get
        {
            return 100 * double.Epsilon;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of an algorithm that involves all faces and vertices of the rectangles (or hypercubes). Thus, it is unfortunately exponential in the number of dimensions. But at least it should be correct.

#### Lemma 1

> Given a point P. The nearest point inside a given rectangle is either P itself or another point on the recangle's boundary/surface.

#### Lemma 2

> Given a point P. The farthest point inside a given rectangle is one of the vertices (corners).

So, if we wanna check if rectangle A is nearer to circle R in comparison to rectangle B, then we search for a counter example. If we can't find one, A is nearer.

Let's say there exists such a counter example (r,a,b). Then we can move the point a even farther away and b even nearer and get an even "stronger" counter example.
And we only check these "strongest" potential counter examples.
So if there is a point r in R, whose farthest point in A is not nearer than the nearest point in B, then A is not nearer to R. But if we can't find such a point r, then A is closer to R, according to jojer's condition.

As Lemma 1 states, we only check b-points on each of the surfaces (edges in 2d) of B.
According to Lemma 2, we only check a-points at the vertices of A.

If we now check all of these a points against all of these b points, divide the space into half and show that the circle is entirely in the half that is nearer to a, then there is no counter example.

The space-division is a compound of 2 hyper-planes and a hyper-parabolas (if we check a vertex of A against a surface of B) See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNpBF.jpg

Thus, we construct all these dividing planes/paraboloids and test if the directional distance of the circle-center is greater than its radius.
If so, then there can be no triple (r,a,b) that makes a counter-example.

The whole process should be just evaluation of some quadratic forms and is dominated by the number of vertex-vertex-pairs and vertex-surface-pairs, which are exponential in the number of dimensions.